# Is there a way to reduce gap between two column headings in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am working on IBM I series VR7, and running SQL(DB2) using CLLE.

I have a SQL procedure in a TXT file, having below command to create a table in QTEMP.

```
create table qtemp.FILE1 as (                                                  
select                                                                          
Field1,Field2,Field3,.....Field10 from FILE2 ) with data;
```

I am calling the above procedure from CLLE using below command.

```
RUNSQLSTM  SRCFILE(MyLib/MySrc) SRCMBR(Proc_txt) COMMIT(*NONE)
```

And then running below command to generate the spool.

```
RUNQRY     QRYFILE((FILE1)) OUTTYPE(*PRINTER) OUTFORM(*DETAIL) FORMSIZE(60 132) 
           FORMTYPE(*STD) COPIES(1) LINESPACE(1)
```

The issue I am facing is that I am getting **2** white spaces between columns while creating the table using the `create table` command. When that table is converted into a spool file using above `RUNQRY` command, the fields on the right side truncates as my report width is **132** by default and I can not change it. 
If the white spaces in the table created can be reduced to **1**, my issue will be resolved. 
The `SQL` I am using IBM i Series' default and `DB2` as database. I don't have much idea about their version.

Edit2: Another issue I had was of report having a field in second line. Actually as per requirement a field had to be in the second row under another field. For example I needed field10 under field5. I have fixed it too, read my answer below.
Hope it helps people in need but I really doubt.

Edit1: I have updated the question as requested. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're doing?  Specifically, what SQL statement(s) are you running, and how are you "converting" the Db2 table to a spooled file?

Comment: And how are you executing the SQL?

Comment: @jtaylor___   I have edited the question. Please have a look and let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Please have a look again.

Comment: So the question is about QRY/400.  Sorry, it's been too many years since I've been forced to use that old product.

Comment: Yes it can. But QRY/400 is extremely outdated and should no longer be used. A 3rd party product called SEQUEL from pathfinder or straight up SQL should be used these days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I needed. As others have suggested, I have finally used WRKQRY to control the column spacing. Reduced the column spacing to 1 and was able to get the columns needed in the 132 width.

Another issue I had was of report having a field in second line. Actually as per requirement a field had to be in the second row under another field. For example I needed field10 under field5. So what I did was, I used the Line wrapping feature available in WRKQRY.

How I did:
Create a WRKQRY object and select the file needed.

1. Sequenced the field I needed in second line, to the bottom.
2. Go to `Select Output Type and Output Form` and take Y on Line Wrapping field. Put the 
   wrapping width equal to your report width. Leave other fields as required.
3. This way each record will have 10th field in next row, if it has data. You can add as 
   many as fields.
4. You may have to add some white spaces to the field for proper alignment. I would 
   suggest to create a new field and use concat(||) operator available in WRKQRY.

Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that yes you can define the report to have 1 space between columns, but you have to define the Query400 object to do that. Unfortunately this is not a good place to write a tutorial for Query400. I can get you started though.

Type wrkqry, press enter.

Then put the cursor on the query name field, and press F4. You are now in the tool. You need to create a new query, and define everything about it in this tool. Play around with it, and see if that helps you.